# Problem getting a follow-up Schengen visa appointment online

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, applications

My friend attended his appointment yesterday at the German embassy in Havana but unfortunately one of the photocopies he presented was deemed unacceptable and he was told to rectify the problem and to book another appointment to proceed with his transit visa application.
The online booking system shows appointments are available this week, but it is rejecting the booking request with an error message saying “passport number must be different. It has already been used for another appointment”.

Does anyone know if it’s normal to have to wait for the system to ‘clear’ a previous appointment, and/or how long this might take? I’ve emailed the embassy but not yet received a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation when applying for a French visa in Canada some years ago. According to the French visa center representatives, it takes 1 day for the system to clear up. Unfortunately, I decided to abandon the application so did not have the chance to verify if it actually takes 1 day. I don't know how much it varies across different Schengen countries though...

Comment: I think a day is correct. I got a response from the Embassy today telling me to try again, which I promptly did and was successful. Although still awaiting the confirmation email…